# Save file in given folder

Tags: django, pdf, save, view, reportlab

I would like to create a pdf file with the tool "reportlab". Afterwards I'd like to save the created file in a given directory (so to say in a given folder)

Here is the code for creating my PDF:

```
def pdfLeereRechnung(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
filename = str("LR_" + str(article) + "_" + str(first_name) + "_" + str(last_name) + "_" + str(date.today().year))
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename + ".pdf"

p = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4) 
#Do something,...
p.showPage()
p.save()
return response
```

Creating the PDF works perfectly, but I don't want to save my files into "Downloads".
So here is my question:
Is it possible, to say something like: p.save_in("C/folder/...")?
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to tell the user agents (their web browsers) where to save downloaded files. It doesn't make sense, you don't even know their folder structure.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to save the files in my server file system..
This project is only running on my localhost..

Comment: Then save your file to server filesystem before returning the response, if any. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files for details.